# How can i make this button with forms using gravity form?

Tags: button, gravity-forms-plugin

this is the site link:  https://www.turkijevisum.nl/visum-aanvragen/

I tried many thing to integrate forms in button  but it's no working.

Button Name:   ( nog een reiziger toevoegen) same fields

Comment: You should post the relevant code here, otherwise we cannot help you. A link to the site is not enough.

Comment: Have you tried design the button in Photoshop? In that case you just go to Form Settings and under Form Button check 'Image' and add 'Button image path'.

Comment: yes, i tried. but it's not working